# Oracle - Why create several service_name in service_names parameter?

Tags: oracle, network, listener

> SERVICE_NAMES specifies one or more names by which clients can connect
>   to the instance. The instance registers its service names with the
>   listener. When a client requests a service, the listener determines
>   which instances offer the requested service and routes the client to
>   the appropriate instance.

What is the reason for I modify the parameter service_names like this

```
Service_names = 'service_one','service_two'
```

Rather than

`Service_names = 'service_one'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the same database you have multiple applications, multiple workloads,... and services help to:
 - identify sessions when troubleshooting performance issue
 - manage resources for those with higher or lower priority
 - balance between several nodes
 - offload some read-only workloads to a standby database
...